# cordova-plugin-firebase-dynamiclinks: Failed to apply plugin [class 'com.google.gms.googleservices.GoogleServicesPlugin']

Tags: android, cordova, ionic-framework, build.gradle, cordova-plugin-proguard

I am trying to build for android after installing **cordova-plugin-firebase-dynamiclinks** plugin. but it throws error.
The error is as follows.

> Error: /Users/user1/ionicProject/platforms/android/gradlew: Command failed with exit code 1 Error output:
>   FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
>
> - Where:
>     Script '/Users/user1/ionicProject/platforms/android/cordova-support-google-services/www-build.gradle' line: 16
> - What went wrong:
>     A problem occurred evaluating root project 'android'.
>     Failed to apply plugin [class 'com.google.gms.googleservices.GoogleServicesPlugin']
>     For input string: "+"

But it is building successfully without this plugin.

currently installed plugin list:

> cordova plugin list

```
com.darktalker.cordova.screenshot 0.1.5 "Screenshot"
cordova-plugin-admobpro 2.29.29 "AdMob Plugin Pro"
cordova-plugin-camera 2.4.1 "Camera"
cordova-plugin-compat 1.2.0 "Compat"
cordova-plugin-email-composer 0.8.11 "EmailComposer"
cordova-plugin-extension 1.5.3 "Cordova Plugin Extension"
cordova-plugin-facebook4 1.9.1 "Facebook Connect"
cordova-plugin-file 5.0.0 "File"
cordova-plugin-file-opener2 2.0.19 "File Opener2"
cordova-plugin-file-transfer 1.7.0 "File Transfer"
cordova-plugin-firebase 0.1.25 "Google Firebase Plugin"
cordova-plugin-inappbrowser 1.7.2 "InAppBrowser"
cordova-plugin-network-information 1.3.4 "Network Information"
cordova-plugin-splashscreen 4.1.0 "Splashscreen"
cordova-plugin-statusbar 2.3.0 "StatusBar"
cordova-plugin-whitelist 1.3.3 "Whitelist"
cordova-plugin-wkwebview-engine 1.1.6 "Cordova WKWebView Engine"
cordova-plugin-x-socialsharing 5.2.1 "SocialSharing"
cordova-sqlite-storage 2.1.2 "Cordova sqlite storage plugin"
cordova-support-google-services 1.0.0 "cordova-support-google-services"
es6-promise-plugin 4.1.0 "Promise"
ionic-plugin-keyboard 2.2.1 "Keyboard"
```

My ionic version details:

```
cli packages: (/usr/local/lib/node_modules)

    @ionic/cli-utils  : 1.18.0
    ionic (Ionic CLI) : 3.18.0

global packages:

    cordova (Cordova CLI) : 7.1.0 

local packages:

    @ionic/app-scripts : 1.3.12
    Cordova Platforms  : android 6.3.0
    Ionic Framework    : ionic-angular 3.1.1

System:

    ios-deploy : 1.9.2 
    ios-sim    : 5.0.13 
    Node       : v6.10.3
    npm        : 3.10.10 
    OS         : macOS High Sierra
    Xcode      : Xcode 9.1 Build version 9B55
```

> cat /Users/user1/ionicProject/platforms/android/project.properties

```
# This file is automatically generated by Android Tools.
# Do not modify this file -- YOUR CHANGES WILL BE ERASED!
#
# This file must be checked in Version Control Systems.
#
# To customize properties used by the Ant build system edit
# "ant.properties", and override values to adapt the script to your
# project structure.
#
# To enable ProGuard to shrink and obfuscate your code, uncomment this (available properties: sdk.dir, user.home):
#proguard.config=${sdk.dir}/tools/proguard/proguard-android.txt:proguard-project.txt
# Project target.
target=android-26
android.library.reference.1=CordovaLib
cordova.system.library.1=com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:+
cordova.system.library.2=com.android.support:support-v4:24.1.1+
cordova.system.library.3=com.android.support:support-v4:24.1.1+
cordova.system.library.4=com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:4.+
cordova.system.library.5=com.android.support:support-v4:+
cordova.gradle.include.1=cordova-plugin-firebase/www-build.gradle
cordova.system.library.6=com.google.gms:google-services:+
cordova.system.library.7=com.google.android.gms:play-services-tagmanager:+
cordova.system.library.8=com.google.firebase:firebase-core:+
cordova.system.library.9=com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:+
cordova.system.library.10=com.google.firebase:firebase-crash:+
cordova.system.library.11=com.google.firebase:firebase-config:+
cordova.system.library.12=com.android.support:support-v4:24.1.1+
```

Please help, totally stuck on this issue.